# make a sync between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to do a sync between two tables:  `TLP` and `glob` in the following way: when changing data in a specific column in `glob` Table  to automatically modify the column in  `TLP` table.
The structure of the two tables are :

```
create table glob 
 ( persone_id number not null ENABLE,
 first_name varchar(10),
 namel varchar(10),
 mail varchar(50),
 country varchar(10),
 porecla varchar (10),
  create_date date default sysdate)
  insert into glob(persone_id,first_name, namel, mail, country) values (14, 'lavinia', 'pop', 'lavinia@yahoo.com', 'France');



create table tlp
  ( given_name varchar(10),
   namel varchar (10),
   email varchar (50),
   poreclat varchar(10),

   create_date date default sysdate);

    insert into TLP(given_name, namel, email) values ('lavinia', 'nedeianu', 'lavinia@yahoo');
```

as you can see, the difference is between `glob.first_name` and `tlp.given_name`. 
I would like to check each row and whether there are differences, `TLP` table to be updated as `glob`but only for users who have the same `email` .

A further condition is that I am not allowed to alter tables.

Comment: Write a [trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm).

Comment: only I know how to do a trigger to 
automatically generate a number. If you could help me ...